# RXJava2 block stream until condition is satisfied

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a queue of files to be uploaded which are emitted by an Observable and I'd like to only upload files when I have a WIFI connection. I've got a solution which will only start emitting the queue when a WIFI connection is established, but ideally I'd like to check before emitting each queue item (and then blocking at this point until a WIFI connection is established). In this way the queue will block items being uploaded if the Wifi is disconnected during the queue upload and resume when it is re-established.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(application)
    .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasState(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
    .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasType(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI))
    .take(1)
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .flatMap { queueItemAvailable() }
    .flatMap { audioSampleUploader.uploadFile(it) }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { // SOMETHING HERE }
```

So I'd like to move the

```
queueItemAvailable()
```

to the top level and then do a (blocking) network connectivity check for each item to upload, but I'm pretty rusty in my RxJava so can't figure out how to this.

Any wisdom is greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you should try to combine the two observables, the one for uploading the items and the one for checking if wifi is available, I think you should move the whole network connectivity check into another method and return on

`ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(application)
    .flatMap { queueItemAvailable() }
    .withLatestFrom {checkForWifiConnection(),  BiFunction<QueueResult, Boolean, Pair< Boolean, QueueResult>>
    { wifiAvailable, queueResult ->
      Pair(queueResult, wifiAvailable)
       }).filter { it.first }
    .flatMap { audioSampleUploader.uploadFile(it) }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { // SOMETHING HERE }`

pardon the code formatting, but the idea is to combine the Observables and return a pair and only emit values when wifi connection is available. I believe you can also use the `zipwith` operator to combine the observables.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how I can use that in this case because it's not obvious to me how this helps.

Comment: `withLatestFrom` will wait until there is an item emitted by all observables being combined, the upstream observable (your source that calls `queueItemAvailable`), and the `checkforWifiFunction`. Once both source observables emit, you can use the BiFunction from withLatestFrom to actually operate on the results of both functions.